# how to use exclude option with pep8.py

Tags: python, pep8

I have a directory structure like this

```
/path/to/dir/a/foo
/path/to/dir/b/foo
```

and want to run pep8 on the directory `/path/to/dir/` excluding `/path/to/dir/a/foo`

```
pep8 --exclude='/path/to/dir/a/foo' /path/to/dir
```

and the expected output of pep8 is, it should not include the files from `/a/foo/`

but pep8 is checking the files inside the `/a/foo/` also

when I do this

```
pep8 --exclude='foo' /path/to/dir
```

it is excluding the files from both and `a/foo` `/b/foo/`

what is the pattern to be given to pep8 exclude option so that it exclude the files only from `/a/foo/` but not from `b/foo/` ?

Answer (score 14):

You can try something like this:

```
pep8 --exclude='*/a/foo*' /path/to/dir
```

The exclude portion uses fnmatch to match against the path as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/blob/master/pep8.py).

```
def excluded(filename):
    """
    Check if options.exclude contains a pattern that matches filename.
    """
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)
    for pattern in options.exclude:
        if fnmatch(basename, pattern):
            # print basename, 'excluded because it matches', pattern
            return True
```

Comment: I think you have to use pycodestyle now or you get a warning. I use `pycodestyle --max-line-length=120 --exclude='*/migrations'`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure I'm reinventing the wheel here, but I have also been unable to get the API working:

```
import os
import re
from pep8 import StyleGuide


def get_pyfiles(directory=None, exclusions=None, ftype='.py'):
    '''generator of all ftype files in all subdirectories.
    if directory is None, will look in current directory.
    exclusions should be a regular expression.

    '''
    if directory is None:
        directory = os.getcwd()

    pyfiles = (os.path.join(dpath, fname)
               for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(directory)
               for fname in [f for f in fnames
                             if f.endswith(ftype)])

    if exclusions is not None:
        c = re.compile(exclusions)
        pyfiles = (fname for fname in pyfiles if c.match(fname) is None)

    return pyfiles


def get_pep8_counter(directory=None, exclusions=None):
    if directory is None:
        directory = os.getcwd()
    paths = list(get_pyfiles(directory=directory, exclusions=exclusions))
    # I am only interested in counters (but you could do something else)
    return StyleGuide(paths=paths).check_files().counters

counter = get_pep8_counter(exclusions='.*src.*|.*doc.*')
```

Comment: I think actually I just didn't understand the unix regex (?) and wanted to use Python's own regex.